# How to reset my current working directory to its default state (current folder wherever script is located) for Python?

Tags: python

Just to give some background info:
I downloaded a range of different IDEs just to try each of them out (VS Code, Spyder, PyCharm Community, Sublime Text). I believe the last IDE I downloaded, Spyder, caused this issue.

Whenever I tried to open a file in Python, it shows an error message of "File or directory does not exist"

I found out the reason why this is happening is because my current working directory had been fixed to "C:\Users\My Username". I don't know how to change it back so that my current working directory is the same as the folder wherever my Python script is located (the default setting before).

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Did you notice whether any of those IDE's installed an environment manager?, you maybe could try to use virtual environments for your projects.

Comment: Never rely on the current working directory, specify the full path for every file you open.  Explicit is better than implicit!

Comment: Yes, but most of the time, the files I need are located in the same folder or in a sibling folder. It would be convenient if my root folder is the folder where my script has been run.

Comment: Could you please help me with this issue? I'd like to reset this setting back to its default state.

Comment: When you say "open a file in Python", what program are you using to open your .py doc? Are you still using Spyder when you get the error?

Comment: I figured it out! I was using the Python Terminus Build System in Sublime Text. For some reason, the default working directory whenever I try to run a Python script using that particular build system (Python Terminus) is "C:\Users\My Username" instead of the location of the Python file. I created a new file in VSCode and ran a "open()" function -  the issue was no longer present.